# Map (1:1) N input sentences to N given sentences by similarity

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, similarity

I want to map `N_a` input sentences to `N_b` given sentences so that the mapping is one-to-one. That is,

- Every `N_a` is assigned
- No `N_a` appears more than once

Unfortunately the inputs vary slightly over time. Here is a representative mapping:

```
{ "typeA":            "step1 typeA (before typeB)"
, "typeD":            "type D"
, "actionA":          "actionA-suffix: typeB or Type D (type E available)"
, "typeE":            "typeE - (not-actionA)"
, "actionB":          "actionB some descriptive words"
, "typeA subtypeA":   "subtypeA typeA or typeX - (not for typeB)"
, "actionA subtypeA": "actionA-suffix: subtypeA (type E available)"
, "typeB subtypeA":   "subtypeA typeB"
, "typeC subtypeA":   "subtypeA typeC"
, "typeB":            "typeB (not subtypeA)"
, "typeF":            "get typeF or typeF-subtypeA"
, "typeF actionB":    "actionB typeF or typeF subtypeA"
}
```

Following [1], I've created this workflow using the `sentence_transformers` package[2]:

- BERT -> mean-pool -> cosine similarity

Given the inputs it is clear that string-based alignment plus edit-distance (of the type featured in `rapidfuzz`[3]) won't work. But I'm not sure if BERT is the best approach, or if it is overkill for my needs. Perhaps I should use a word embedding model (word2vec, glove, etc) rather than a sentence embedding model. For this particular task I wonder if BERT could be tweaked to perform better.

The categories aren't well differentiated so that BERT sometimes maps an input to more than one given. An input `N_a` can be the best match for multiple givens `N_b0, ..., N_bi`. In such cases I keep the map with the best score and for the others fall upon the 2nd-best, 3rd-best, ... map. How can I improve BERT's performance to avoid these duplicates?

---

Current implementation below:

```
import pandas as pd
import sentence_transformers as st

model = st.SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')

sentences_input = [ ... ]
sentences_given = [ ... ]

# Create the encodings and apply mean pooling.
enc_input = model.encode(sentences_input)
enc_given = model.encode(sentences_given)

# Calculate a cosine similarity matrix
cos_similarity = st.util.cos_sim(enc_input, enc_given)

# As a pandas dataframe, label the matrix with the sentences.
df = pd.DataFrame\
  (columns=sentences_input, index=sentences_given, dtype=float)
for i, sgiven in enumerate(sentences_given):
  for j, sinput in enumerate(sentences_input):
    df.loc[sgiven, sinput] = cos_similarity[j,i].item()

# For each given sentence, extract the best-scoring input sentence. Which
# unfortunately is not a one-to-one mapping.
mapping_bad_duplicates = df.idxmax(axis=1)

# Create a one-to-one mapping by iterating over the matches in order of best
# score. For each map, blocklist the row and column sentences, preventing
# duplicates.
mapping_good = {}
by_scores = sorted(df.unstack().items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
sentences = set(sentences_input) | set(sentences_given)
for (sinput,sgiven), score in by_scores:
  if not sentences:
    break
  if sgiven not in sentences or sinput not in sentences:
    continue
  mapping_good[sgiven] = sinput
  sentences.remove(sgiven)
  sentences.remove(sinput)

# Convert the result to a dataframe
mapping_good_df = pd.Series(mapping_good)
```

1. [BERT For Measuring Text Similarity](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-for-measuring-text-similarity-eec91c6bf9e1)
2. [SBERT: Semantic Textual Similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html)
3. [rapidfuzz](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/fuzz.html#rapidfuzz.fuzz.partial_ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for any fancy NLP at all. This looks like a relatively straightforward [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). For a string `a` of `a_list` and a string `b` of `b_list`, define `score(a, b)` to be the number of words in common of `a` and `b`, and then solve the assignment problem to maximise the scores.

Below I didn't even properly solve the assignment problem, and instead returned a greedy solution, and yet it still found the best matches:

```py
def score(a, b):
    b_words = b.replace('-', ' ').split()
    return sum((w in b_words) for w in a.split())

def greedy_matching(a_list, b_list):
    b_available = set(b_list)
    for a in sorted(a_list, key=len, reverse=True):
        b = max(b_available, key=lambda b: score(a.lower(), b))
        yield (a, b)
        b_available.remove(b)

a_list = ['typeC subtypeA', 'actionA', 'typeD', 'typeE', 'typeF', 'actionA subtypeA', 'typeB', 'typeF actionB', 'typeB subtypeA', 'actionB', 'typeA subtypeA', 'typeA']

b_list = ['typeB (not subtypeA)', 'typeE - (not-actionA)', 'actionB some descriptive words', 'get typeF or typeF-subtypeA', 'type D', 'subtypeA typeA or typeX - (not for typeB)', 'step1 typeA (before typeB)', 'subtypeA typeC', 'actionA-suffix: subtypeA (type E available)', 'subtypeA typeB', 'actionB typeF or typeF subtypeA', 'actionA-suffix: typeB or Type D (type E available)']

b_list = [s.lower().replace('type ', 'type') for s in b_list]
pairs = list(greedy_matching(a_list, b_list))

print(*pairs, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
('actionA subtypeA', 'actiona-suffix: subtypea (typee available)')
('typeC subtypeA', 'subtypea typec')
('typeB subtypeA', 'subtypea typeb')
('typeA subtypeA', 'subtypea typea or typex - (not for typeb)')
('typeF actionB', 'actionb typef or typef subtypea')
('actionA', 'actiona-suffix: typeb or typed (typee available)')
('actionB', 'actionb some descriptive words')
('typeD', 'typed')
('typeE', 'typee - (not-actiona)')
('typeF', 'get typef or typef-subtypea')
('typeB', 'typeb (not subtypea)')
('typeA', 'step1 typea (before typeb)')
```

Comment: Heh! But I wanted fancy NLP toys... I'll have to look at this tomorrow, but some quick thoughts. 1] I think you're getting very lucky in iteration order. There are many ties in your greedy version that wouldn't be solved by a full implementation of the assignment problem. 2] "-suffix "is a lexical suffix that changes the word form so that `assert("actionA" not in "actionA-suffix")`. 3] The only way to break the ties is with a semantic understanding of the word "not"

Comment: 4] My input fluctuates with time and it is likely that in the future or with input I have yet to encounter, the ties won't break in my favor. 5] If I understand correctly, the loop over `by_scores` in my question is a full solution to the assignment problem 6] The implementation in my question is Deep Learning Transformer (BERT) + Assignment Problem which ideally should simplify to just BERT.

Comment: Ah, excuse me. Regarding [5], that loop is greedy over global scores (rather than greedy per sentence), which could still lead to local maxima, though I think it is less likely especially thanks to BERT. Regarding [1], it *might* be solved by a full implementation, but given the number of ties I think that's too unlikely to leave to chance.

Comment: Hey! We could take your greedy solution and apply it twice. Split the given sentences into 2-3 related clusters, and apply the solution to determine which cluster. Apply it again to determine the specific sentence. Basically, it excludes words which are common on ties. On a related note, if the number of clusters equals the number of given sentences, then you're basically hardcoding a list of keywords in an if/elif tree... but you need to sort the input sentence words correctly because the order can affect ties. That's the first thing I tried: it felt brittle, overly verbose and too hardcoded.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at this and confirmed that due to ties, this answer depends on iteration order: change `for a in sorted(a_list, key=len, reverse=True):` -> `for a in a_list:` and the results are completely different.

Comment: @user19087 Of course the results depend on the order. It's a greedy algorithm. I wrote it in about 2 minutes. Use a proper Hungarian algorithm to solve the assignment problem. You don't have to code your own, there are several libraries that provide one. The point of the greedy algorithm was to illustrate in 2 minutes of code how good the results were with a very simple score function.

Comment: The complete assignment algorithm performed much more robustly than I expected. I used `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`. I only needed to hard-code some lexical mappings to work around [2]. Despite the many ties arising from [3], and even after I introduced some keywords that scored several incorrect inputs higher than the correct assignments, the algorithm always returned the correct result. I completely underestimated the cumulative effect from incorrect assignments, despite the low dimensionality and having so many alternative combination-pairs with equivalent scores.